# How to merge and format column elements from multiple csv files and dump it in new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, shell, csv

I have multiple CSV files. All of them has  single id column

in A.csv

```
ID
---
01487
01986
01478
```

in b.csv

```
ID
---
01578
01568
01478
```

I want to create a CSV from these CSV files where 
c.csv

```
ID
----
01487
01986
01478
01578
01568
01478
```

I have seen column wise concatenate but i want my  all id's in same column one after another. 
I have seen panda concatenation but cant format like this. Any python panda based solution or  shell command solution is appreciated

Comment: are you dataframes in a list? just call assuming that list is called `dfs` call `pd.concat(dfs)`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in shell:

```
cat a.csv >> c.scv
tail -n 2 b.csv >> c.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/mydir")

def merge_all_csv(extension='csv',final_file_name="final_csv"):
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    #combine all files in the list
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
    #export to csv
    return combined_csv.to_csv( final_file_name, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

merge_all_csv()
```